# How to query newest item from table with duplicate items?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to deal with data that is being dumped to a "log" table within SQL Server. Unfortunately can't make changes. Basically a process is run daily which dumps some duplicate items into a table.

Table 1:

```
import_id: guid
import_at: datetime
```

Table 2:

```
item_id: guid
import_id: guid (foreign key)
item_url: varchar(1000)
item_name: varchar(50)
item_description: varchar(1000)
```

Sometimes Table 2 will have a duplicate item_url. I only want to get the list of item_id and item_url from the newest import.

Comment: explain more, with sample data and expected output, you want duplicates in result or not!!!??? if no, which of them(duplicates) do you want to come in result!!!???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will return one row per item_url, the one with the latest import_at value:

```
WITH all_items AS (
    SELECT
          t1.import_id
        , t1.import_at
        , t2.item_id
        , t2.item_url
        , t2.item_name
        , t2.item_description
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_url ORDER BY t1.import_at DESC) AS item_url_rank 
    FROM dbo.table1 AS t1
    JOIN dbo.table1 AS t2 ON
        t2.import_id = t1.import_id
    )
SELECT 
          t1.import_id
        , import_at
        , item_id
        , item_url
        , item_name
        , item_description
WHERE 
    item_url_rank = 1;
```